# Excel VBA - Referencing a named range in a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet where the amount of 'items' in a list can change depending on the number of items in an order. I have a template tab which I then use to create a specific tab for each order.

I want to create a formula that counts the number of items in this list as part of a macro I have which gets all of the information from each order and puts into a master tracker.

I have named the range of the item codes using a rows.count function so that it only looks at the exact number of items.

I am trying to then include a formula in the macro using this named range however when the macro runs and puts the formula into the designated cell it doesn't recognise the cells I want it to look at and only contains the name of the range.

The part of the code I want to look at is below.

```
Dim ReqItems, SuppItems As Range

Set ReqItems = Form.Range("E16:E" & lastrow)
Set SuppItems = Form.Range("H16:H" & lastrow)

Tracker.Range("Q" & lastrow2).Formula = "=COUNTIF(ReqItems,"">0"")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to fill in the address into the string.

```
.Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & ReqItems.Address & ","">0"")"
```

---

Please also note that

```
Dim ReqItems, SupItems As Range
```

only declares `SupItems As Range` but `ReqItems` will be of type `Variant` here. You will need to declare a type for **every** variable.

```
Dim ReqItems As Range, SupItems As Range
```